# Post back in Acumatica grid

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

In Acumatica, how can I post back when I am selecting a new row on a grid by simply clicking on the row and not updating any values?

I am looking to set a UI element depending on the position of the current selected element in the grid, but on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Acumatica Framework does not synchronize the currently selected record in a grid with the Current property value of the appropriate PXCache, mostly to improve the performance. However by setting the **SyncPosition** property value to ***True*** for the PXGrid will invoke the sync operation every time the user selects a row in the grid.